# How does the select() function behave in C

Tags: c, networking

I am confused as to how the select function works. Till now I thought that it just checks all the sockets which have been set in the fd_set structure that we provide it as arguments. But on reading about the function from here [https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/select.html#:~:text=The%20select()%20function%20tests,descriptors%20are%20ready%20to%20read](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/select.html#:%7E:text=The%20select()%20function%20tests,descriptors%20are%20ready%20to%20read).

> The nfds argument specifies the range of file descriptors to be tested. The select() function tests file descriptors in the range of 0 to nfds-1.

This suggests that all the socket descriptors are checked, even those which are not even in the list.
Can somebody confirm if this is how it works?

Comment: From the `man` page: *The nfds argument specifies the range of descriptors to be tested. The first nfds descriptors shall be checked **in each set**; that is, the descriptors from zero through nfds-1 in the descriptor sets shall be examined.*

Comment: `This suggests that all the socket descriptors are checked, even those which are not even in the list.` This is irrelevant. It is up to the implementation (kernel) to decide what to check. But the contract with the caller is "only report on fds in the range 0 .. nfds-1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `nfds` argument acts as an upper bound on the file descriptors to check.  The function doesn't actually check all file descriptors in that range, just the ones listed in one of the `fd_set` parameters.

It's actually common to use `FD_SETSIZE-1` for this parameter, where `FD_SETSIZE` is a macro that defines the limit on file descriptor numbers that `select` will accept.

Comment: _It's actually_ **so** _common to use `FD_SETSIZE-1` that I haven't seen it in three decades of Unix programming, and I'm glad I didn't have to wonder why the person who used it unnecessarily excluded the highest numbered member of `fd_set` from being usable.